# escape sequence? using quotes in Qstring

Tags: c++, c, qt, escaping

I'm using Qt creator 2.4. I need to use a string say `hi"world"` in my code. I have tried to use `Qstring` and `std::string` and I know `/` is the escape sequence character but the IDE doesn't understand it as an escape sequence and gives errors when I write:

```
"hi/"world/""
```

I can use any string format that can be converted into `Qstring`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the backslash for escape sequences: `\"` not `/"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
QString output = "Hi \"world\"!";
```